# Bind C-\ from variable in tmux

Tags: tmux

In `.tmux.conf`, the following works as expected:

```
bind -n C-\ display-message 'hello'
```

I am trying to bind a key defined in a variable, say `key`.
I have made the following two attempts:

```
a=C-\
bind -n $a display-message 'hello'
# Produces: unknown command: -n

a=C-\\
bind -n $a display-message 'hello'
# Produces: unknown key: C-\\
```

Is there a way to achieve what I'd like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess in the first case the `\` before newline makes the line continue or something.

This should work:

```
a='C-\'
bind -n $a display-message 'hello'
```

Comment: Ha, I tried many things but not that. Thank you!